# How to get the plus symbol to display correctly in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm developing a website in which I need to show the `+` (plus) symbol. On all other browsers the encoded `&plus;` seems to display fine.

How to get the plus symbol to display correctly in IE?

Comment: are you talking about URL encoding?

Comment: @LieRyan - I think it depends on the client browser encoding. I need to have a hex/html code to represent it

Comment: @LouisTan - No, just the HTML mark up encoding

Comment: for example multiply is &times  not x or *

Comment: @IEnumerable: + is an ASCII character so it do not need character reference unless you are using one of the more obscure encodings that does not agree with ASCII on its 0-127 range AND is serving the document with misleading HTTP Header which implies that you won't be able to rely what you written as <, > are tag opener and closer either and will get a much more messed up document than just incorrect plus sign. In short, just use + and be done with it, the only way to mess up + is if you have a buggy text editor or web framework that multiplexed multiple encoding into a single document.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [This site](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm). It has a good list of HTML codes

`&#43;` should do the trick

Comment: yes it now works in all browsers :), I even changed the browser encoding a couple of times and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Type the character “+”. There is no magic in the reference `&plus;`, which simply stands for the common “+” character, rather pointlessly. It belongs to the large set of added “[named character references](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/named-character-references.html#named-character-references)” in HTML5 drafts; this part of the draft was completely unimplemented about a year ago, so it’s only supported by fairly recent versions of browsers. It was probably added just for MathML compatibility.

The “named character references” are defined in terms of Unicode numbers of characters, so you can always use references like `&#x2b;` or `&#43;` instead of them (though for this character, there is no need to use anything but the character itself).

This is not comparable with `&times;`, which is a standard, universally supported reference, for a character that cannot be directly typed on most keyboards. (But there’s always some way of entering “×” directly, too.)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, there now appears to be an excellent HTML5 document detailing all of these Character Entities, at http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref.

Specifically in regards to `&plus;`, however, there is not much point in using a named entity for it, because it is already part of the standard 7-bit ASCII (being `&#x0002B;` and `&#43;`), and thus the character is the same regardless of the encoding -- whether in DOS, Windows, Unix, or UTF-8, thus there is usually not much point in using anything other than a straight plus symbol for it up front (which is not the case for other things like `&mdash;`, which requires at least an 8-bit encoding, and is thus less safe to represent as straight text, depending on the environment).